# Setting up multiple sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I have setup a uitableview with custom cells.

I would like these into sections with a title. Looking at the below photo I am looking for the following layout:

Section - My Profile
Custom cell - wwwwwwwwwwwwww...
Section - Application
Custom cell - Games
Custom cell - Share
Custom cell - Rate
Custom cell - Settings
Custom cell - Help 
Custom cell - Log out

I can see how to add a section and control the rows in a section, but this duplicates the cells into multiple sections, I am not sure how to have one section with one row and another section with 6 rows. I also want to style these sections to show, slightly like the Facebook menu style.

Should I create custom cells for the actual sections instead and have no action on the section (cell) selection?

Here is the code for the UITableView

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
LeftMenuTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeftMenuTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (UIView *view in views) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (LeftMenuTableViewCell*)view;


        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could define number of sections and rows in it as following:

```
- (UIView *) tableview:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView view;
    if(section == 0) {
         // Initialise view for section 1
    } else {
         // Initialise view for section 2
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return ((section == 0) ? 1 : 6);
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // return appropriate cell(s) based on section
    if(indexPath.section == 0) 
    {
        // Return 1 cell
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1) 
    {
        switch(indexPath.row) {
            case 0: // Initialize cell 1
                    break;
            case 1: // Initialize cell 2
                    break;
            ...
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great. What I am looking for is to style the section header as such. Is this possible, or would I need a custom cell for the first cell (section header). In my question Section would act as the header for the custom cell. So if I do need a custom cell it would be custom section cell, then custom cell, then custom section cell, then 6 other custom cells...?

Comment: You can add different views in section using `viewForHeaderInSection` . I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks I can add this. But how should I style the sections? As in should they be custom cells, or I should code the subview?